# Delete this in mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've created a class to hold an interface component on one of my web pages. There is an `add` button to instantiate the class and insert the new element into the DOM. I want to give the class a `remove` method to remove the element from the dom, and then destroy the instance.

I have this:

```
// can have multiple tags
var Tag = new Class({
    Implements: [Options, Events],
    this.targetElement: undefined,
    this.tagName: undefined

    initialize: function() {
        this.targetElement = new Element('input', { class: 'tag' });
        this.targetElement.inject($('tagHolder'));

        ...
        // event handler to set `this.tagName` to contents of the input
        ...

        if (Tag.tags === undefined)
            Tag.tags = [];
        Tag.tags.push(this);
    },
    remove: function () {
        this.targetElement.destroy();
        delete this;
    }
```

this removes the element from the DOM, but does not delete the instance object.

I want to use the array `tag.tags` to get access to all the tags the user has created, so if the user deletes a tag, I want that tag to be removed from the array, or be set to `undefined`, or similar. As the tag instance is then no longer needed, it makes sense to delete/prepare for GC the object at this point so that memory isn't wasted.

How should I do this, or is this a silly method? Is there a better way?

Comment: You can only `delete` properties in an object, so `delete this` is never possible. Where do you define the `Tag` variable? If it is a global variable, `delete window.Tag` would do the trick, since global variables are automatically properties of `window`.

Comment: @pimvdb new instances come from a `click` event: `$$('.addTag').addEvent('click', function () { new Tag() });` I don't have any handle on the instances other than through `Tag.tags`.

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck. See it this way - the object can be stored in multiple variables, so there is not a one-to-one relationship between an object and "its variable". Anyway, what would you like to delete in that example?

Comment: @pimvdb I was hoping I might be able to get at the underlying data and delete it, with the result that all pointers to that data return "undefined" or something... I guess this isn't possible.

Comment: Just assign the new instance of Tag into a variable which is defined in a scope. Once out of the scope, that variable is no longer needed and should be handled by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use [`Array.erase`](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Types/Array.js#L120) w/o any problems.

change your remove method to:

```
remove: function () {
    this.targetElement.destroy();
    Array.erase(Tags.tags, this);
    // reset reference
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I just realised I could do something similar to this, but I was trying to use `Array.filter` instead.

Comment: `this = null` is invalid syntax.

Comment: +1 yeah left side assignment, silly lunchtime code. can't really self-destroy. perhaps it should try to GC from the outside